# How to run a Java service in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: java, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have initialized a Jenkins pipeline with the following script. The pipeline reported a successful run, but the application has no response at all. Please help me.

This is my pipeline script

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
             steps {
                script {
                   git credentialsId: '3',
                   url: 'git@github.com:myusername/myproject.git'
                   sh "git checkout master"
                  }
               }
        }
        
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean package'
                sh 'mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true'
                sh 'mv target/my-project-0.0.1.jar target/my-project.jar'
            }
        }
    
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sh 'java -jar target/my-project.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is pipeline last line log:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ mv target/my-project-0.0.1.jar target/my-project.jar
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
[Pipeline] sh
+ java -jar target/my-project.jar
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Did you check that the application is configured correctly to listen on the expected port and interface?

Comment: Review the application logs to check for any errors or exceptions that might be occurring during startup. This Jenkins log does not show the application log.

Comment: Instead of piping the logs to `/dev/null` you might want to temporarily send it to a file; and archive it to the build for more information (via `archiveArtifacts(...)`). Also, in my understanding, using `2>&1` routes stderr to stdout; so the Job would never show as failed or show that `sh(...)` failure information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins auto-kills the process after deploy. I just add JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe to the script.

Full script:

> `sh 'export JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe && java -jar target/my-project.jar &'`